# how to attach javascript file and use them when built dll file

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

I have a solution contain one class library and one JavaScript file. I want build it into dll file and then call a function in that file.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a web project (which I'm assuming) why do you want to do it this way? Is this for deployment of your single library to others?

You need to embed this as a resource which wil lthen use ScriptResource.axd.

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.handlers.scriptresourcehandler.aspx